# NSDate from NSString

Tags: ios4, nsstring, nsdateformatter

I need to convert string in the format of "Jan 2nd, 2011 11:38am" in to corresponding NSDate.
I used following code to convert the string to date.

```
+ (NSDate *) dateFromString: (NSString *) dateString {      

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return dateFromString; 
}
```

but it returns nil.
Can any one please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+ (NSDate *) dateFromString: (NSString *) dateString 
{       
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return dateFromString; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this
NSDate *dateFromString = [[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString] retain];
and in return statement
return [dateFromString autorelease];

or
in place of [dateFormatter release];
you have to use
[dateFormatter autorelease];

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString 
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    return date;
}
```